# How to access a remote desktops active directory? (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I'm trying to connect to a remote desktops active directory.

When I ping the remote desktop I get a response back, so is it possible to connect to it?

Currently, when I connect locally while on the remote desktop, I use the following code: (It works)

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.ApplicationDirectory, "doris-dev", "cn=" + SupplierName + ",cn=suppliers,o=doris");

UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, Username);
```

I use the same code when I try to remotely connect to the machine, but then the exception message says it needs a username and password. Which username and password is this? Where does it come from?

Comment: With ping you can get if it's *not* possible to connect. For possibility checking use `Telnet` and `port`, to which you are trying to connect.

Comment: @SeM You can't even do that. Device firewalls might block pings but allow remote management services such as WMI and WRM.